# Why is there a horizontal asymptote for y = 5 according to limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Horizontal asymptotes of f(x) are given by lim f(x) x-> +-oo

let f(x) = 5

We have lim 5 x-> +-oo = 5. Therefore, there is a horizontal asymptote at y = 5, according to my math.

This seems very strange because there is supposedly a horizontal asymptote at y = 5. but f(x) is always touching y = 5.

Why is this?

Comment: What definition of "*asymptote*" are you using? Many (most?) don't preclude `always touching`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of the function $f(x)=5$, if you go far enough to the left or right, looks like the straight line $y=5$. That's what an asymptote is, intuitively, and there's nothing mysterious about it.